# Noncapturing patterns with vi or sed

Tags: regex, sed, vi

I have a file with about 100,000 lines. Is there a good regex I could use with vi or sed to convert the input file to the output? The pipe delimited part of the line can contain hundreds of entries

To sum up what needs to be done, I need to capture an expression at the beginning of the line which is then appended to every entry (i.e. it appears before any pipe or the end of the line)

**Input**

```
G1778-BRAZIL    .A3_Alagoas|.A5_Amazonas|.B3_Bahia|.C4_Ceara|.D5_Distrito Federal|.E8_Espirito Santo|.G6_Goias|.G8_Guanabara
G2807-ATLANTIC OCEAN    .B3_Baffin Bay|.M4_Mexico, Gulf of|.N55_North Atlantic Ocean|.N6_North Sea
```

**Output**

```
G1778-BRAZIL    .A3_Alagoas+G1778-BRAZIL|.A5_Amazonas+G1778-BRAZIL|.B3_Bahia+G1778-BRAZIL|.C4_Ceara+G1778-BRAZIL|.D5_Distrito Federal+G1778-BRAZIL|.E8_Espirito Santo+G1778-BRAZIL|.G6_Goias+G1778-BRAZIL|.G8_Guanabara+G1778-BRAZIL
G2807-ATLANTIC OCEAN    .B3_Baffin Bay+G2807-ATLANTIC OCEAN|.M4_Mexico, Gulf of+G2807-ATLANTIC OCEAN|.N55_North Atlantic Ocean+G2807-ATLANTIC OCEAN|.N6_North Sea+G2807-ATLANTIC OCEAN
```

Comment: What exactly is unclear? I'm trying to convert the input lines to the output via regex.

The pattern at the beginning can easily be captured with ^\(G[^ ]*]\) but appending it to an arbitrary number of entries that precede pipes or the end of the line is unclear.

Comment: Turns out awk with $1 used in the replacement component of a simple gsub expression was a far easier approach

Comment: `^(G[^ ]*])` wouldn't capture `G2807-ATLANTIC OCEAN`. What is that space before .A3 and .B3 - a tab or multiple blank chars?

Comment: if you simply did that given your posted sample input it would not produce your posted expected output.

Comment: Sure it does. cat myfile | awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"}{OFS="\t"}{gsub(/\||$/, "+"$1"|",$2)}{print $1,$2}' |sed 's/|$//' worked just fine. Yeah, I threw in the sed to strip off the trailing pipe, but it was a quick and easy solution

Comment: You also threw in the FS setting and the OFS setting and the regexp and the print of specific fields and a UUOC....

Comment: That has to do with how the website software stripped what I wrote. The issue here was how to set up the replace as the capture was very straightforward

Comment: No need to do things the hard way. In any case, breaking lines into fields is generically useful for drastically simplifying a wide range of complex replacements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

idk if that first long space is a tab or multiple blanks so this will work either way assuming the captured string doesn't contain any backreference metacharacters (e.g. `&`)::

```
$ awk -F'  +|\t' '{gsub(/[|]|$/,"+"$1"&")}1' file
G1778-BRAZIL    .A3_Alagoas+G1778-BRAZIL|.A5_Amazonas+G1778-BRAZIL|.B3_Bahia+G1778-BRAZIL|.C4_Ceara+G1778-BRAZIL|.D5_Distrito Federal+G1778-BRAZIL|.E8_Espirito Santo+G1778-BRAZIL|.G6_Goias+G1778-BRAZIL|.G8_Guanabara+G1778-BRAZIL
G2807-ATLANTIC OCEAN    .B3_Baffin Bay+G2807-ATLANTIC OCEAN|.M4_Mexico, Gulf of+G2807-ATLANTIC OCEAN|.N55_North Atlantic Ocean+G2807-ATLANTIC OCEAN|.N6_North Sea+G2807-ATLANTIC OCEAN
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I see what you're doing now.

```
perl -F'/[\s|]+/' -nE '
    BEGIN { $, = " " }
    $a = shift @F; 
    say $a, join "|", map {"$_+$a"} @F
' file
```

or

```
gawk -F'[[:blank:]|]+' '{
    printf "%s ", $1
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) printf "%s+%s%s", $i, $1, i == NF ? ORS : "|"
}' file
```